# How can I aggregate across fields after opening a json l in python pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am reading some data in from a json object and then converting that into a dataframe using pandas.to_json(). After I do this, I want to perform an aggregation on the resulting data frame, by counting the number of values by a particular variable. Here's a data type summary of the dataframe.

```
df3.types
id        object
origin    object
dtype: object
```

When I try to execute

```
df3.groupby(['origin']).count()
```

But that generates an error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

I'm not clear on how to proceed.

I've tried converting both id and origin explicitly to strings, but that doesn't get me anywhere.  In R I would just convert origin to a factor, and in SQL this would be a breeze.  Can anyone give me a suggestion on how to proceed?

Comment: Could you show your data?

Comment: No, not even if I hash the values- strictly verboten. I could make totally synthetic data if that helps, but the first column contains just unique string values (guarenteed to be unique every time), but the second column is not.  That said, I just noticed that origin is actually a single dict- something I hadn't noticed before- so I think I have to go and extract those elements.

Comment: Yes from the error it seems that the column origin contains a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clue to the solution is indicated in the error, I just didn't understand the error. The data had the format of

```
id, origin
'someIdentifier', '{'id':'someNonUniqueIdentifer'}'
```

The solution is thus to extract the value of the 'id' within the single element dict inside the dataframe, like this

```
df3['new_origin'] = [x['id'] for x in df3['origin']]
```

now the command

```
df3.groupby(['new_origin']).count() works exactly as required.
```

Thanks to everyone's help.